# How to create custom rules in sonarqube for dotnet?

Tags: .net, sonarqube, rules

I want to create custom rules in SonarQube for Dotnet language . please share the idea .

Answer (score 1):

As of today, custom FxCop rules are supported by the SonarQube plugin. However, I'd recommend that you start developing your own rules based on Roslyn, the .NET Compiler Platform. These cannot yet be integrated out of the box in SonarQube with the C# plugin, but it is something we're going to add soon: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-456

If the rules you want add can also be valuable to other users, then feel free to submit them as pull requests to the SonarLint Visual Studio project: http://www.github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vs